# Sub querying documents using mongoose in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 schemas:

```
const shop = new mongoose.Schema({
id:String,
name:{type: String , required:true},
address:String,

reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
    reviewText: String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}

});
```

Using mongoose I want to query a specific review using review id in a particular shop.
My api will be like this:
http://localhost:3000/api/locations/:shopId/reviews/:reviewId
I looked in the documentation but it is working with other paths such as author but not with id.

Answer (score 0):

```
const location = await Loc.findById(req.params.locationId)
const result = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewId);
```

This method gives the correct results using mongoose.